# regex for japanese characters

Tags: java, regex

I have a pattern regex for check matching string:

`\b(\w+)(?:株式会社|会社)(?:\s*)(\w+)(?:ご担当者様|様)`

Problem: this pattern does not matching japanese characters

Example:

> CompanyA株式会社Daniz様

=> match this pattern.

but

> スタッフ株式会社本社様

=> does not match this pattern

How i can change regex to match (japaneses characters, special character, and normal character a-z A-Z 0-9)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Unicode properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/unicode.html#properties) to match different classes of characters. For example to match any letter in any language you can use `\p{gc=IsL}` instead of `\w`, which matches just Latin letters (plus underscore and digits). Or you can use specific script for just Japanese characters. In your question it's not clear if you want any letter or just Latin + Japanese letters. Also, what "special characters" do you want to include?